# With Trinomial's, can someone explain the purpose of the first, second and third term. In layman terms.

Tags: quadratics

I know that the first term is a quadratic and I suppose that lets us know we are dealing with identifying a curve, and the third term is our constant. I just can't quite put it all together as how they are actually working together. Such as what relationship that have to each other.. Help.

Comment: I'm speaking of equations like, x^2 + 2x +15. I'm wanting to understand what the question is really asking and what type of problems would require or could be answered with this type of equation.

Comment: Quadratics will be much easier to visualize if you convert them to $y = A(x - j)^2 + k$.  Before that though you have to learn general theory like $f(x - j)$ is $f(x)$ shifted to the right by $j$.

Comment: Just for reference: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647753/how-can-one-calculate-iiii/

Answer (score 2):

For the function $y=x^2 + bx + c$, where the lead coefficient is $1$, the second coefficient $b$, with its sign flipped, tells you the sum of the two $x$-intercepts, while the constant term $c$ tells you their product.

In the case of $x^2+2x+15$, you know that, if it has $x$-intercepts, then their sum is $-2$ and their product is $15$. There are no two real numbers satisfying those conditions, so this quadratic has no $x$-intercepts.

Does this address the question you're asking?